# Clean up a dimension table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My dimension tables contains more rows than my fact table, I would like my dim table fields to show only the values in the fact table when used as a filter in the filter panel.What cleaning/modeling steps are the best to achieve this.

I also know how to write sql if that is an option for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use a table for your dimension, use a view that has an inner join to the fact table

Comment: ok thats a good idea thanks I was going to do that but if I have multiple fact tables using the same dimension tables will that not mean I need to create dimension views for every fact table. Currently I was reusng my dimensions for as many reports as I can.

Comment: That is probably why using a data warehouse is better than a database which you are afraid to bloat up with views. In a data warehouse you can just create as many objects as you like I guess

Comment: A view is essentially a query, so you are not storing multiple copies of the same data. It is just fetching a "view" of the data. Alternatively, if a given fact table always requires the same dimension records, you could just use the dimansion table in your filter and put and the filter the displayed records in the filter.

Comment: i found a workaround so instead of creating views with inner joins I am using inner join in the native query section of power bi get data this way I can reuse my dimension views across as many reports as possible as each report has a different fact table but more or less the same dimension table